# A lemma about free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let F be a finitely generated free group and $\gamma_m$ the lower central series.
Why is $\gamma_m(F)/\gamma_{m+1}(F)$ torsionfree? I know it is abelian, but I couldn't find out more about it, as multiple commutators get very messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just torsionfree, it's free abelian. The basic commutators of weight $m$ are a basis. This is proven in Hall's *Group Theory* book, and is Hall's Basis Theorem (due to Phillip Hall).